# Get the path of link that it points to?

Tags: linux, solaris, aix, symlink, hp-ux

Is it possible to get the abolute path of the link that it is pointing to?
Is there any simple system command?

I need for all of the following OS 
HP-UX 11i, 1123u, 1123i
AIX 5.2 and 5.3
Suse Linux 10
Solaris 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify a language, so I assume you want a command that can be run in whatever shell you are using.  The [`ls`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/ls.html) command has the `-l` (that is an ell) option which prints out a lot of information about the file.  The last bit of information is the full path, so you should be able to say

```
ls -l file | awk '{print $NF}'
```

on any SUS2 compliant machine (which should be all of the commercial UNIXes).  This will have a problem if the file or the any of the directories leading up to the file have spaces though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a system call, you want [`readlink(2)`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readlink.html). This is standardized, and so should be available on all POSIX compliant systems.

Here's an example of its usage, taken from the link given earlier:

```
#include <unistd.h>

char buf[1024];
ssizet_t len;

if ((len = readlink("/modules/pass1", buf, sizeof(buf)-1)) != -1)
    buf[len] = '\0';
```

If you're looking for a command line utility, it doesn't look like there is one standardized, but [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html%5Fnode/readlink-invocation.html) (Linux) and [BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.1-RELEASE&format=html) both have `readlink(1)`.

Comment: how sad its not levelled across.